# Retrieve a query from a SSIS SQL task via C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ssis

I am looking for a way to programmaticly pull the all SQL statements from hundreds of dtsx files. I am already pulling the connection string and type by creating a package instance as seen below. I'm hoping for a solution that will allow me to access a SQLTask object via the package

```
        Application app = new Application();
        Package dtsPkg = new Package();
        dtsPkg = app.LoadPackage(dtsxFilePath, null);
        app.LoadPackage(dtsxFilePath, null);
        ConnectionInfos connectionInfos = app.ConnectionInfos;
        Connections connections = dtsPkg.Connections;
        foreach (ConnectionInfo x in connectionInfos) {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Connection Type " + x.ConnectionType);
        }

        foreach (ConnectionManager cm in connections) {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Connection String " + cm.ConnectionString); 
        }
```

Comment: Will the query always be a direct query (inline) or could the source use query from variables and therefore you need to identify what the Variable is and then potentially worry about whether it has expressions set on it and/or it is set via some mechanism?

Comment: You want to retrieve al sql statement inside ever sql task?, you have like 20% done, which version of SQL Server are you using?